# How to store data with tablets?

Tags: apache-flex, tablet

I want to develop a tablet app , in that app I want to store records ( like database records ). In J2ME we can use recordstores to store data inside smartphones. So how can we store data inside tablets ?

NB : I dont know at the moment the language I will use to develop the app , but I will use certainly flex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try SqlLite.   Here is a short description: http://www.redminnow.com/news/sqlite-and-mobile-app-development/